# Need to write two results in same excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

```
 xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        OleDbDataAdapter dscmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select distinct Ticket_no from Tickets where date_dt='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' and Type='Closure'  and queueName='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", cont1);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(ds);
        OleDbDataAdapter dtcmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("select distinct Ticket_no from Tickets where date_dt='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' and Type='Reassigned'  and queueName='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", cont1);
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        dtcmd.Fill(dt);
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Closure";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Reassigned";

        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {

                data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;

            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("Ticket_Closer_"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()+".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

I need to write the 1st select query results in 1st column, and 2nd select query results in 2nd column of the same excel sheet. Please help me to code it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my English, translation google translate makes.
I have this written in VB.NET that you can quickly re-write in C# class.

Here one of the many online tools that translate vb.net to C#
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

If you wish, you can have an Excel file without information, reads the empty file in memory, then writes the result of a DataTable type variable directly on the object and then save it. This is my preferred method, manipulate DataTable in memory is much faster
This is an example of how to implement it

```
Dim ColDef As xlsRW.fldType
ColDef = New xlsRW.fldType
ColDef.fldName = "FieldName"
ColDef.fldSize = 200
ColDef.fldType = xlsRW.FieldsType.char
xlsWriter.ColumnAdd(colDef)
ColDef = New xlsRW.fldType
ColDef.fldName = "DateField"
ColDeffldType = xlsRW.FieldsType.date
xlsWriter.ColumnAdd(colDef)
xlsWriter.CreateWorkbook("WB")
```

Esta es la clase

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Collections
Public Class xlsRW
  Public Enum FieldsType As Byte
    [char]
    [date]
    [float]
    [currency]
  End Enum
  Public Structure fldType
    Public fldName As String
    Public fldSize As UShort
    Public fldType As FieldsType
    Public fldValue As Object
  End Structure
  Private blnHasHeader As Boolean = True
  Private strSheetName As String = String.Empty
  Private strFileName As String = String.Empty

  Private blnXLSOpen As Boolean = False
  Private oleConn As OleDbConnection
  Private oleCmd As OleDbCommand
  Private oleDA As OleDbDataAdapter
  Private htFields As New Hashtable
#Region " Properties "
  Public Property FileName() As String
    Get
      Return strFileName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      strFileName = value
    End Set
  End Property
  Public Property SheetName() As String
    Get
      Return strSheetName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      strSheetName = value
    End Set
  End Property
  Public Property HasHeader() As Boolean
    Get
      Return blnHasHeader
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
      blnHasHeader = value
    End Set
  End Property
  Public ReadOnly Property IsXLSOpen As Boolean
    Get
      Return blnXLSOpen
    End Get
  End Property
#End Region
  Public Sub Open()
    If strFileName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Filename was not assigned.")
    End If
    Me.Open(strFileName)
  End Sub
  Public Sub Open(ByVal strFileName As String)
    Try

      Dim strConn As String = String.Empty
      If IO.Path.GetExtension(strFileName).ToLower = ".xls" Then
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;READONLY=FALSE;"""
      ElseIf IO.Path.GetExtension(strFileName).ToLower = ".xlsx" Then
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;READONLY=FALSE;"""
      End If
      If Not blnHasHeader Then
        strConn = strConn.Replace("YES", "NO")
      End If
      oleConn = New OleDbConnection
      oleConn.ConnectionString = strConn

      oleConn.Open()
      blnXLSOpen = True
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  End Sub
  Public Sub ColumnAdd(colDef As fldType)
    If htFields.ContainsKey(colDef.fldName) Then
      Throw New Exception("Field already exist")
    End If
    Dim strField As String = String.Empty
    strField = colDef.fldName & " " & colDef.fldType.ToString
    If colDef.fldType = FieldsType.char Then
      strField += " (" & colDef.fldSize & ")"
    End If
    htFields.Add(colDef.fldName, strField)
  End Sub
  Public Sub ColumnRemove(colDefName As String)
    If Not htFields.ContainsKey(colDefName) Then
      Throw New Exception("Field doesn't exist")
    End If
    htFields.Remove(colDefName)
  End Sub
  Public Sub ColumnUpdate(colDef As fldType)
    If Not htFields.ContainsKey(colDef.fldName) Then
      Throw New Exception("Field doesn't exist")
    End If
    Dim strField As String = String.Empty
    strField = colDef.fldName & " " & colDef.fldType.ToString
    If colDef.fldType = FieldsType.char Then
      strField += " (" & colDef.fldSize & ")"
    End If
    htFields.Item(colDef.fldName) = strField
  End Sub
  Public Sub ColumnClear()
    htFields.Clear()
  End Sub
  Public Sub CreateWorkbook(ByVal strSheetName As String)
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If htFields.Count = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("No fields defined.")
    End If
    Try
      oleCmd = New OleDbCommand
      oleCmd.Connection = oleConn
      Dim strCmdText As String = "CREATE TABLE " & strSheetName & " ("
      For Each strFldDesign As String In htFields.Keys
        strCmdText += htFields(strFldDesign) & ", "
      Next
      oleCmd.CommandText += strCmdText.Substring(0, strCmdText.Length - 2) & ")"

      oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
  End Sub
  Public Sub Close()
    oleConn.Close()
    blnXLSOpen = False
  End Sub
#Region " Select "
  Public Function SelectWorksheet() As DataTable
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Try
      oleDA = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" & strSheetName & "$]", oleConn)
      Dim dsXLS As DataSet = New DataSet(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName))
      oleDA.Fill(dsXLS)
      dsXLS.Tables(0).TableName = strSheetName
      Return dsXLS.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
      Return Nothing
    End Try
  End Function
  Public Function SelectWorksheet(ByVal strCell As String) As Object
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Dim strCellRange As String = strCell & ":" & strCell
    Try
      oleCmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" & strSheetName & "$" & strCellRange & "]", oleConn)
      Return oleCmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
      Return Nothing
    End Try
  End Function
#End Region
#Region " Insert "
  Public Sub InsertWorksheet(ByVal aryValues As ArrayList)
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Try
      Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
      oleCmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * From [" & strSheetName & "$]", oleConn)
      oleDA.SelectCommand = oleCmd
      Dim dsXLS As DataSet = New DataSet(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName))
      oleDA.Fill(dsXLS, strSheetName)
      Dim strInsertCmd As String = String.Empty
      Dim strColumn As String = String.Empty
      strInsertCmd = "INSERT INTO [" & strSheetName & "$] ("
      For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
        strInsertCmd += "[" & dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Item(bteCnt).ColumnName & "], "
      Next
      strInsertCmd = strInsertCmd.Substring(0, strInsertCmd.Length - 2)
      strInsertCmd += ") VALUES ("
      For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
        strInsertCmd += "?, "
      Next
      strInsertCmd = strInsertCmd.Substring(0, strInsertCmd.Length - 2) & ")"
      oleDA.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(strInsertCmd, oleConn)
      For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
        strColumn = dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Item(bteCnt).ColumnName
        Select Case aryValues.Item(bteCnt).GetType.Name
          Case "String"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.VarChar)
          Case "DateTime"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Date)
          Case "Decimal", "Int32"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Numeric)
          Case "DBNull"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Empty)
        End Select
        oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Item("@" & strColumn).Value = aryValues.Item(bteCnt)
      Next
      oleDA.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      oleDA.Update(dsXLS, strSheetName)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  End Sub
  Public Sub InsertWorksheet(ByVal drRow As DataRow)
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Try
      Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
      oleCmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * From [" & strSheetName & "$]", oleConn)
      oleDA.SelectCommand = oleCmd
      Dim dsXLS As DataSet = New DataSet(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName))
      oleDA.Fill(dsXLS, strSheetName)
      Dim strInsertCmd As String = String.Empty
      Dim strColumn As String = String.Empty
      strInsertCmd = "INSERT INTO [" & strSheetName & "$] ("
      For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
        strInsertCmd += "[" & dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Item(bteCnt).ColumnName & "], "
      Next
      strInsertCmd = strInsertCmd.Substring(0, strInsertCmd.Length - 2)
      strInsertCmd += ") VALUES ("
      For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
        strInsertCmd += "?, "
      Next
      strInsertCmd = strInsertCmd.Substring(0, strInsertCmd.Length - 2) & ")"
      oleDA.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(strInsertCmd, oleConn)
      For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
        strColumn = dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Item(bteCnt).ColumnName
        Select Case drRow.Item(bteCnt).GetType.Name
          Case "String"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.VarChar)
          Case "DateTime"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Date)
          Case "Decimal"
            oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Numeric)
        End Select
        oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Item("@" & strColumn).Value = drRow.Item(bteCnt)
      Next
      oleDA.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      oleDA.Update(dsXLS, strSheetName)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  End Sub
  Public Sub InsertWorksheet(ByVal dtData As DataTable)
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Try
      Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
      oleCmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * From [" & strSheetName & "$]", oleConn)
      oleDA.SelectCommand = oleCmd
      Dim dsXLS As DataSet = New DataSet(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName))
      oleDA.Fill(dsXLS, strSheetName)
      Dim strInsertCmd As String = String.Empty
      Dim strColumn As String = String.Empty
      For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtData.Rows
        strInsertCmd = "INSERT INTO [" & strSheetName & "$] ("
        For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
          strInsertCmd += "[" & dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Item(bteCnt).ColumnName & "], "
        Next
        strInsertCmd = strInsertCmd.Substring(0, strInsertCmd.Length - 2)
        strInsertCmd += ") VALUES ("
        For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
          strInsertCmd += "?, "
        Next
        strInsertCmd = strInsertCmd.Substring(0, strInsertCmd.Length - 2) & ")"
        oleDA.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(strInsertCmd, oleConn)
        For bteCnt As Byte = 0 To dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Count - 1
          strColumn = dsXLS.Tables(strSheetName).Columns.Item(bteCnt).ColumnName
          Select Case dtData.Columns(bteCnt).DataType.Name
            Case "String"
              oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.VarChar)
            Case "DateTime"
              oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Date)
            Case "Decimal"
              oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" & strColumn, OleDbType.Numeric)
          End Select
          oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Item("@" & strColumn).Value = dtRow.Item(bteCnt)
          'oleDA.InsertCommand.Parameters.Item("@" & strColumn).SourceColumn = strColumn
        Next
        oleDA.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Next
      oleDA.Update(dsXLS, strSheetName)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  End Sub
#End Region
#Region " Update "
  Public Sub UpdateWorksheet(ByVal aryFields() As String, aryValues() As Object, strWhere As String)
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Try


    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  End Sub
  Public Sub UpdateWorksheet(ByVal strCell As String, objValue As Object)
    If Not blnXLSOpen Then
      Throw New Exception("Connection is unassigned or closed.")
    End If
    If strSheetName.Length = 0 Then
      Throw New Exception("Sheetname was not assigned.")
    End If
    Try
      oleCmd = New OleDbCommand(String.Empty, oleConn)
      oleCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [" & strSheetName & "$" & strCell & ":" & strCell & "] SET F1 = ?"
      Dim oleType As OleDbType
      Select Case objValue.GetType.Name
        Case "String"
          oleType = OleDbType.VarChar
        Case "DateTime"
          oleType = OleDbType.Date
        Case "Decimal"
          oleType = OleDbType.Numeric
      End Select
      oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@F1", oleType, 0, "F1")
      oleCmd.Parameters(0).Value = objValue
      oleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
      Throw ex
    End Try
  End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```